# Handling two way navigation in WP7?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

basically when my app loads my first screen is MainPage.xaml, which I'm treating as a loading screen. This is to make an update to screen appear faster. From the loading screen the user is automatically navigated to another page that contains content called Content.xaml respectively.

The problem is navigating the first way works fine,

> SpashScreenImage --> MainPage.xaml --> Content.xaml

but if the user decides to hit the back button they go to the loading page, but then that navigates them back to the content page.

> MainPage.xaml <-- Content.xaml
>   MainPage.xaml --> Content.xaml

This looks real easy to solve if I knew what page they were coming from.
Is there a way to detect what page the user is navigating from? That way I could handle it properly.

**EDIT:** My main objective is to get the animation that occurs when you navigate to a Panorama page in WP7 (Slide effect). So far the only way I've been able to trigger this event is by manually navigating to the page, like I suggested in my question (Content.xaml == Panorama Page), or by reactivating the app on that page.

Comment: so what you want to do when User presses back button from Content.xaml.You want to Quit the application or you want to be in MainPage.xaml?

Comment: What hosts the navigation frame?

Comment: @Vaysage yes that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. The application would exit.

Comment: @Derek I'm not sure what you mean but I'm also open if there is another way of accomplishing it.

Comment: Are you using the navigation frame?  Posting some code might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest approach here is to avoid the transient loading/splash page altogether, by making it a full-screen UserControl that sits on top of your Content.xaml page.

When the loading is complete, just set Visibility=Collapsed on the UserControl and you are immediately on your content page.

Now when the user presses back, your app exits as expected.

This approach also works great when your app is Tombstone'ed.

Comment: yes this is currently the method I am using. See there is a brief animation that appears when you navigate to a "Panorama Page" in wp7. So far the only way I've been able to trigger this is by manually navigating to the page or reactivating the app on that page. By using a UserControl, the page just appears.

Comment: The other option you can try in your scenario is to use UriMapper to redirect the initial navigation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx